# Setting up multiple machines to be in selenium grid using Docker compose

Tags: windows, docker, selenium-grid

I am having trouble creating a selenium grid using 2 machines.

I am trying to use docker compose, and host the hub on one machine with the 2 machine just connecting nodes and ultimately some load balancing.

```
seleniumhub:
 image: selenium/hub
 ports:
  - 4444:4444

chrome:
image: selenium/node-chrome
links:
 - seleniumhub:hub
```

above is my yml file and this runs fine and I am able to scale it easily with the following command

```
docker-compose up -d --scale chrome=5
```

but my question is if I had the 2nd machine how would I spin a node up on that machine and hook/link it to the hub on the 1st machine.

I have seen forums using links, networks, and environments but nothing is working from my end.

Does anyone know of a decent guide to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

i would say to use docker-swarm, so your **2nd machine** would become *swarm worker* node of **1st machine** [here](http://www.mchubarov.com/2017/02/running-selenium-grid-with-docker-in.html) is some example, also [this](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-selenium-grid-using-docker) one

Comment: Its a nice guide but again it doesnt seem to work when i follow the guide, when i try and add the 2nd machine to the swarm i get the following error.

'Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable'

However I carry and get the yml in place but when I execute it the console doesn't load up although it seems everything executed as expected, the services are running and when I docker ps can see the containers running but the webpage suggests otherwise.